# Phusion Passeger Error

Tags: carto, apache, ruby

so i am installing the [cartodb platform](https://gist.github.com/arjendk/6080388) locally i have followed all the procedures succesfully but i have a phusion passenger spawn error. I am looking for working solutions and i haven't any to be suitable. This is the error that is being written in my apache2 error log file.

```
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:07.9911 19232/7fa0b25ec700 age/Log/Main.cpp:346 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:07.9912 19232/7fa0b8739780 age/Log/Main.cpp:408 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:07.9912 19232/7fa0b25ec700 Ser/Server.h:455 ]: [LoggerAdminServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:07.9913 19232/7fa0b8739780 age/Log/Main.cpp:433 ]: PassengerAgent logger shutdown finished
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:08.0249 19249/7f8f7eb83780 age/Wat/Main.cpp:1264 ]: Starting PassengerAgent watchdog...
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:08.0391 19254/7f8588f91780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:891 ]: Starting PassengerAgent server...
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:08.0392 19254/7f8588f91780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:234 ]: PassengerAgent server running in multi-application mode.
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:08.0406 19254/7f8588f91780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:645 ]: PassengerAgent server online, PID 19254
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:08.0543 19259/7f38b04c0780 age/Log/Main.cpp:439 ]: Starting PassengerAgent logger...
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:08.0550 19259/7f38b04c0780 age/Log/Main.cpp:320 ]: PassengerAgent logger online, PID 19259
[Tue Mar 31 17:38:08 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.0.5 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
App 19360 stderr: SpawnPreparerShell: /home/webserver/cartodb20/home/webserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@cartodb/gems/passenger-5.0.5/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent: No such file or directory
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:24.1406 19254/7f8588e83700 App/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/webserver/cartodb20: An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger.
  Error ID: b372329d
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-rRhQZc.html
  Message from application: An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
<pre>SpawnPreparerShell: /home/webserver/cartodb20/home/webserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@cartodb/gems/passenger-5.0.5/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent: No such file or directory
</pre>

[ 2015-03-31 17:38:24.1450 19254/7f8583093700 age/Hel/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is b372329d. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 19433 stderr: SpawnPreparerShell: /home/webserver/cartodb20/home/webserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@cartodb/gems/passenger-5.0.5/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent: No such file or directory
[ 2015-03-31 17:38:26.6031 19254/7f8588e83700 App/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/webserver/cartodb20: An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger.
  Error ID: 28bdb5a8
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-sudl8r.html
  Message from application: An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
<pre>SpawnPreparerShell: /home/webserver/cartodb20/home/webserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@cartodb/gems/passenger-5.0.5/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent: No such file or directory
</pre>

[ 2015-03-31 17:38:26.6072 19254/7f8583093700 age/Hel/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 28bdb5a8. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
                                                                                                                                                                    658,117       98%
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this line suggesting that you may have not properly installed passenger?

SpawnPreparerShell: /home/webserver/cartodb20/home/webserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@cartodb/gems/passenger-5.0.5/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent: No such file or directory

What about "Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-sudl8r.html"?
What does that file says?

CartoDB should work fine with Passenger. However if you have too much problems you can always start it with any other rack server like mongrel, thin or unicorn.